# Just updated to Magento 1.9.3 and i get this when trying to view my account page

Tags: magento

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_group_price.is_percent' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`is_percent` FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE (entity_id='3378') AND (website_id = 0)

Trace:
#0 /app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[42S22]...')
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[42S22]...')
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1641): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(964): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '3378', NULL)
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '3378', NULL)
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(836): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('3378')
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(778): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_canReorder(false)
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Reorder.php(61): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->canReorder()
#9 /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/recent.phtml(62): Mage_Sales_Helper_Reorder->canReorder(Object(Emagicone_Mobassistantconnector_Model_Order))
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/8com/publ...')
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Recent.php(95): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Recent->_toHtml()
#15 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('top', true)
#17 /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('top')
#18 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/8com/publ...')
#19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#20 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('customer_accoun...', true)
#24 /app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#25 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#26 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /app/design/frontend/breeze/8com/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/8com/publ...')
#32 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/breeze...')
#33 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#36 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#37 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#38 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#39 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#40 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#41 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#42 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#43 /index.php(68): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: you probably forgot to update your db after dumping in the new 1.9.3 code.

Comment: how i can do it now ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Ok ty anyway @Enigmativity

Comment: @Alexandros - Why "OK ty **anyway**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. Looking at the output log, the update process had failed to clear the cache so I logged on to the FTP and manually deleted the contents of /var/cache/. All sorted!